# NFS/SMB - cluster phenomen (blade center / synology / multi nic)

Tags: nfs, server-message-block, ipv4

I hope someone can help me as we have in the company a strange issue and not even our network experts have an idea.

The setup: We have a hyper-v cluster hosted on 16 blades in a HPE blade Center/enclosure. Each blade runs win server 2016 datacenter edition full version. All of them have the hyper-v role assigned and are also failover clustered. All hosts and guests work fine "as fine hyper-v can be compared to esx". No connection issues no drops or fails on any of the 200 guest machines. In addition we have a synology rackstation in the same rack just a few units above the the blade Center with about 300TB SAS hdd space. This is used for many different purposes but nothing business critical and has the SMB/NFS options enabled for file sharing over network. The synology has 5 netwok adapters. 1 1Gb and 4 10 Gb adapters. The 10Gb adapters are bonded together and might be used as 1 single adapter with 40Gb speed. There are cause of this 2 IP addresses where you may access the synology.

The issue: After logging in to some of the hyper-v servers and trying to open a connection to the synology workstation (file explorer) 40 Gb interface we have a strange issue where not all shares are displayed and all you see is the NFS share list \volume1\share1 \volume1\share2 \volume2\share1 etc but you cant see the the SMB shares for some reason. Accessing from the same machine the 1Gb interface and the default SMB share is presented with all the folders.

We don't have this issue on all servers inside the cluster so I suspect its a windows config thing that prevents correct communication - i might be wrong. Anyone has any idea how to figure out what's going on here?

Thanks a lot!